# How to change my URL from http://localhost to http://myurl.myservice.com in ASP.Net MVC5?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am developing a server with ASP.Net MVC5 in Visual Studio 2013.

I am trying to run the test server with my DDNS url so I tried to change my URL from "localhost" to "myurl.myddnsservice.com" in Project URL field in my project settings file.
But it does not work with the message "Unable to launch IIS Express."

I have searched so many times in this site but I could not find the answer.

Does anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I got it. I needed to reserve a URL in my Windows using:

netsh http add urlacl url=http://myurl.myddnsservice.com/ user=Everyone